# Values not getting into Firebase Database 9.0.2 from Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to push new values into firebase database but it's not showing into my Firebase account i.e. the data is not getting pushed. I have given read/write permission in my firebase console. The internet permission is also there along with all latest gradle dependencies. Here is my code by which I am trying to push the data:

```
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());


                // Write a message to the database
                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();


                Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                updates.put("USER_ID", user.getUid());
                String version ="-";
                try {
                    PackageManager manager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
                    PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo(
                            getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 0);
                    version = info.versionName;
                    updates.put("APP_VERSION", version);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    updates.put("APP_VERSION", version);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                updates.put("FIRE_TOKEN", FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
                myRef.setValue(updates);

                Log.d(TAG, "Database Executed.\nVersion:"+version+"\nUSER_ID:"+user.getUid()+"\nFIRE_TOKEN:"+FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());



            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }

    };
```

Note that the line below is logging all the values perfectly too.

```
Log.d(TAG, "Database Executed.\nVersion:"+version+"\nUSER_ID:"+user.getUid()+"\nFIRE_TOKEN:"+FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

Make a model class of user like this

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class User {

    public String username;
    public String email;

    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public User(String username, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }

@Exclude
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("username", username);
    result.put("email", email);


    return result;
}
}
```

then for saving the data at firebase database

```
String key = mDatabase.child("user").push().getKey();
        User user = new User( username,email);
        Map<String, Object> postValues = user.toMap();

        Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
        childUpdates.put("/user/" + key, postValues);
        mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Jagjit but its not working. I tried this too.

Comment: Android studio is failing to resolve post.toMap();. It would be great if you can help me with that. Is that user.toMap()?

Comment: @Adhish Lal tomap is functions in userclass

Comment: @AdhishLal its working at my my end. Please make you have correct Json file

Comment: Exactly post is failing here to resolve:

Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114713/discussion-between-jagjit-singh-and-adhish-lal).

Comment: Yes I found that but its not working. Let me check the JSON